# SQL Query with n number of WHERE-arguments in VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, variables, iteration

I’m using ADO to run SQL query in VBA. I’ve done this quite a lot, and everything works properly.

However, I’m advancing to a more sophisticated query, where I need to input an unknown number of conditional strings. In short:

```
SELECT * FROM database.dbo.table
WHERE Col1 IN (‘val1’, ‘val2’, ..., ‘valn’)
```

I have a set of data on my worksheet, which changes every time. The data are of the same string format each time, but number of cells with values varies. I want to execute above query, using my `n` number of variables in the `WHERE`-statement.

**Example of query with 5 variables from worksheet:**

```
SELECT * FROM database.dbo.table
    WHERE Col1 IN (‘000165234’, ‘000165238’, ‘000165231’, ‘000165232’, ‘000165239’)
```

Any pointers to the right direction are greatly appreciated.
My biggest issue is how to handle the unknown number of variables.

**Constraints**: will always be at least 1 cell with value, and never more than 60.

**Notes**: Data is also stored in an array, and does not necessarily needs to be printed on the worksheet.

**Updated code**

```vb
    Sub TEST()
    
        Dim ws1 As Worksheet
        Dim ws2 As Worksheet
        
        Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        
        Dim fRow As Long
        Dim sRow As Integer
        Dim col As Integer
        Dim arr() As Variant
        Dim coll As New Collection
        
        col = 3
        sRow = 6
        
        With ws1
            fRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
        End With
        
        With ws2
            fRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row
        End With
        
        
        For i = sRow To fRow
            With ws1
                ele1= .Cells(i, 2).Value
                ele2= "000" & .Cells(i, 4).Value
                If ele1<> "" Then
                    coll.Add Array(ele2)
                End If
            End With
        Next
        
        On Error GoTo gotcha
        
        ReDim arr(1 To coll.Count, 1 To 2)
        
        For i = 1 To coll.Count
        
            arr(i, 1) = coll(i)(0)
    
        Next
        
    gotcha:
        Debug.Print Err.number
    
        If Err.number = 9 Then
            MsgBox "Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    
        ws2.Range("L29:M" & fRow2).ClearContents
        ws2.Range("L29").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
        
        Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        
        Dim fRow3 As Long
    
        With ws2
            fRow3 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row
        End With
        
      
        Dim CONNECTION As String
        Dim QUERY As String
        
        Dim WHERE As String
       
        'Set connection and SELECT query
        CONNECTION = "Provider=*.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*; Password=*; Data Source=*;Initial Catalog=*"
           
    
        selectpart = "SELECT *FROM database.dbo.table "
          


       '### The error occurs here ###            
       conditionpart = "WHERE [COL1] IN ('" & Join(arr, "','") & "')"

       GetBreakerQuantitiesQuery = selectpart & vbNewLine & conditionpart
        
       QUERY = GetBreakerQuantitiesQuery
    
        conn.Open CONNECTION
    
        Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
         
        rs.ActiveConnection = conn
        rs.Open QUERY
        
        ws.Range("T6").CopyFromRecordset rs
        ws.Range("T6:AL6").Copy
        ws.Range("N7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, True, True
        ws.Range("T6:AL6").ClearContents
        ws.Range("L6").Select
            
        rs.Close
        conn.Close
        
        Set conn = Nothing
        Set rs = Nothing
        
    End Sub
```

Comment: `arr` should be a single-dimension array, not a 2-d array if you want to use `Join()`

Comment: So change to ws2.Range("L29").Resize(UBound(arr, 1)).Value = arr ? Is that sufficient to make it 1D? I need ele1 to handle a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Dim sql as string, arr

arr = Array("000165231", "000165232", "000165239")

sql = "SELECT * FROM database.dbo.table WHERE Col1 IN ('" & Join(arr, "','") & "')"

'use sql variable for your query
```

Use a 1-d array:

```
For i = sRow To fRow
    With ws1
        If Len(.Cells(i, 2).Value) > 0 Then
            coll.Add "000" & .Cells(i, 4).Value
        End If
    End With
Next

On Error GoTo gotcha '??

ReDim arr(0 To coll.Count-1)

For i = 1 To coll.Count
    arr(i - 1) = coll(i)
Next

'....
ws2.Range("L29").Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! However, im getting the error: Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument, for variable sql.

Comment: That's not really telling me much about the exact problem you're having - maybe update your question to add the new code, the exact error message, and indicate which line it's being raised by.

Comment: Thanks. Updated with complete code. Error message at highlighted spot: Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: Thanks alot! It worked very well when changing to 1D-array! :)